# gradle sync failed network is unreachable (connect failed): Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip 46ms

Tags: android-studio

I had this error when trying to view a project in Android Studio:

gradle sync failed network is unreachable (connect failed): Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip 46ms

What can be the cause? I have not found anything googling for half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by myself: I was connected to an IPv6 only WIFI and apparently, the gradle distribution website does not support IPv6.